# Why does background-color on BODY "bubbles up " to HTML

Tags: css, background-color

See code below.

I have not explicitly set background-color on html parent, so why does it get bg color of its child ?!

```css
/* uncomment to see
html {
  background-color:orange;
}*/
body {
  background-color:hotpink;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    body<br/>
    <p> hey some random para</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nitheesh Yes, it does. (the answer seems to be It's just how it works without it making sense - a feature, not a bug)

Comment: That duplicate question explains in details to what you want to know.